# ANOVA model (test) on Data Frame in Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, anova

I have a data frame in Scala that contains two columns (Y which is continuous and X which is categorical (A to J)). I need to perform ANOVA test on this data frame and i am wondering if you could provide me with the necessary steps to perform this test?
I tried to find a solution online and i came across the following link:
https://gist.github.com/srnghn/c74835818802fefabd76f1bcd6746831/revisions
However, since i am new in Scala, i could not figure out how to run the ANOVA function in the code on my data frame?
Thank you so much in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to map your data to `Dataset[CatTuple]` if you'd like to run that code, then call the `getAnovaStats` function with that dataset.

More details (this an example how to create a data set, you should convert your data to this format):

```
final case class CatTuple(cat: String, value: Double)
val data = Seq(CatTuple("a",1.0), CatTuple("b",1.0), CatTuple("a",1.5)).toDS() 
val anovaStats = getAnovaStats(data)
```